# Converting -moz-linear-gradient For All Other Supporting Browsers

Tags: cross-browser, css, mozilla

Here's my rule:

```
#element {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #FFF 8px, #F2F2F2 24px, #F2F2F2 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #F2F2F2;
}
```

I want to take that rule and apply it to all of the browsers that support a linear gradient. **What would this rule's syntax look like for Chrome, Safari, and ... Internet Explorer?**

I'm considering making a super simple web app that will take a CSS file with Mozilla rules and kick out the other browser's implementations of the rules as well.

Comment: a very good question, why do i need to regenerate my css since i already got it right for Mozilla, all what i need is to convert it to other browsers. 

If you found such solution, please share it with us. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the gradients as requested...

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EEFF99), to(#66EE33));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
```

Comment: Thanks Robert - but these don't match the given rule in the question

Comment: Yeah, I figured you were capable of swapping out the colors and direction to match if you're capable of making a tool to generate code based on one rule.

Answer (score 3):

This site do the trick : http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Choose "Import from css" from the "CSS" zone and paste your code !!!

You can try with something like "`background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgb(216,54,33), rgb(112,5,7));`" for exemple.

Be carefull : code must be formated a certain way... if there is space after comma (", ") for exemple this do not work...

Answer (score 2):

It's not too hard... But [this website (css-tricks.com)](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) can explain it much better than I can.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is already available here: [CSS3 Gradient Generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/) - that works for Mozilla and Webkit-based (Safari/Chrome) browsers.

As for IE, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28VS.85%29.aspx) should help you.

Comment: Even if I knew this website for a long time now, I still didn't think about using it to convert my existing gradients. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something along the lines of

```
// Firefox
background: -moz-linear-gradient
// Chrome & Safari
background: -webkit-gradient
background: -webkit-linear-gradient
// Opera
background: -o-linear-gradient
// IE
background: -ms-linear-gradient
```

It's probably as crossbrowser solution as you're going to get - but then again CSS is not my forte.